# How to migrate SVN repository to existing SVN repository with history and with different target path

Tags: svn, migrate

For my current project I have to move my existing SVN repository with structure:

```
/myproject/trunk/code
```

to

```
/existing/server/projects/myproject/trunk/code
```

whilst preserving history. I have access to both repositories.

I have found the current options, but I feel unsure about the solution:

```
svnadmin dump / load - Can this load into an existing repository?
svnsync - Can this load into an existing repository with a different path?
```

Any idea how I can solve my problem?

Comment: As an SVNKit developer, I know one solution. But it involves some programming (using SVNKit, libsvn or AlienSVN depending on your favourite language). If you won't find any ready to use solution, ping me, I'll describe, how to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Providing you have the same settings and versions of SVN server, why not stop both servers and just make a tarball to copy ?

*PS. how easier it is with Git that just does not have database at all :-)*

Comment: -1: And how exactly would you merge the two tarballs? How would the revision numbers and logs correspond?

Comment: merge ? the word was "move". If that was merge or just restructure of directory tree was not told.

Comment: Actually, I suspect this is the correct/simplest answer; the OP doesn't seem to want to *merge* two repos - he simply wants to move the contents of one dir structure into another that happens to be on a different server.

Comment: on the second glance, that might be something like external repo or such. Or anything at all. With no info given on layout in sVN any folder might be anything at all.